# Passing a hash as an initial value when creating an object

Tags: ruby

I am making a `Temperature` class with instance methods that convert the temperature from f to c, and vice-versa. A test case is:

```
Temperature.new(:f => 32).in_celsius #=> 0
```

I thought that passing `:f => 32` would give the conversion. I don't know how to extract the value `32` from the hash `:f => 32`. I want to extract that so that I can convert that number either into f or c.

Below is my answer code.

```
class Temperature      
  def initialize(f = 0, c = 0)
    @f = f
    @c = c 
  end

  def in_fahrenheit
    c = @c * 1.8
    c += 32
    @f = c.floor
    @f 
  end

  def in_celsius
    f = @f - 32
    f /= 1.8
    @c = f.floor
    @c 
  end

  def fahrenheit
    @f 
  end 

  def celsius
    @c 
  end
end
```

I am not familiar with hashes passed as initial values when creating objects. I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I am new to ruby and my question was that passing a hash `:f => 32` is new too me and I don't know how to extract the value inside that pair(`32`). I want to know how to extract that so that I can convert that number either into f or c.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: You can also use [keyword arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15062570/when-to-use-keyword-arguments-aka-named-parameters-in-ruby) which is basically a shorthand to taking a hash argument and assigning properties to variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `initialize` method is looking for two parameters, but your input contains only one, the hash. Here's how you can handle a hash containing Fahrenheit:

```
  def initialize(temp)
    @f = temp[:f] 
  end
```

If you want to handle input in either F or C, I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

Comment: Does that apply if I have two parameters? ex: 

`def initialize(temp)
@f = temp[:f]
@c = temp[:c]
end`

Comment: You may have a single hash with as many keys as you want. Though honestly, I have no idea why you'd want to accept input containing both F _and_ C, when your class does conversions for you.

Comment: Wait what do you mean? Do you mean that I don't need to def initialize?

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I think I'd do it something like:

```
class Temperature

  def initialize(input)
    puts "in #{self.class}.#{__method__}, input.class.name is: #{input.class.name}"
    @f, @c = input[:f], input[:c]
  end

  def in_fahrenheit
    return @f if @f
    c = @c * 1.8
    c += 32
    @f = c.floor
    @f 
  end

  def in_celsius
    return @c if @c
    f = @f - 32
    f /= 1.8
    @c = f.floor
    @c 
  end

  def fahrenheit
    return @f if @f
    in_fahrenheit
  end 

  def celsius
    return @c if @c
    in_celsius
  end

end
```

As Mark Thomas points out, `initialize` is receiving a `Hash`:

```
> t = Temperature.new(f: 32)
in Temperature.initialize, input.class.name is: Hash
 => #<Temperature:0x0000000996cbf8 @f=32, @c=nil>
```

BTW, `f: 32` is a bit more modern than `:f => 32`, I believe.

I added in some `return` statements. That way, you can do:

```
> t = Temperature.new(f: 32)
 => #<Temperature:0x00000009856ca0 @f=32, @c=nil> 
> t.fahrenheit
 => 32 
> t.celsius
 => 0 
> t.in_fahrenheit
 => 32
> t.in_celsius
 => 0
```

And:

```
> t = Temperature.new(c: 0)
 => #<Temperature:0x0000000986b038 @f=nil, @c=0> 
> t.fahrenheit
 => 32 
> t.celsius
 => 0 
> t.in_fahrenheit
 => 32 
> t.in_celsius
 => 0
```

As Mark also said, you *could* do:

```
t = Temperature.new(f: 32, c: 32)
```

But, that would give you all sorts of erroneous results. So, if you wanted to protect against that, you could do:

```
class Temperature

  def initialize(input)
    puts "in #{self.class}.#{__method__}, input.class.name is:"<<" #{input.class.name}"
    @f, @c = input[:f], input[:c]
    raise "Only one input, please!" if @f and @c
  end

  def in_fahrenheit
    return @f if @f
    c = @c * 1.8
    c += 32
    @f = c.floor
    @f 
  end

  def in_celsius
    return @c if @c
    f = @f - 32
    f /= 1.8
    @c = f.floor
    @c 
  end

  def fahrenheit
    return @f if @f
    in_fahrenheit
  end 

  def celsius
    return @c if @c
    in_celsius
  end

end
```

Which would give you something like:

```
> t = Temperature.new(f: 32, c: 0)
in Temperature.initialize, input.class.name is: Hash
RuntimeError: Only one input, please!
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I figured it out as soon as I learned that I can use a hash plus key to get the value.

Comment: No problem. I'm just avoiding my own work, TBH. Hope it wasn't too much.

Answer (score 0):

You're incorrectly mixing different argument styles.

#### Positional Arguments

Judging by your call `Temperature.new(:f => 32)` you seem to think that `def initialize(f = 0, c = 0)` offers hash or keyword arguments. It doesn't. That's just two positional arguments (with defaults, so they're optional). Let's print out what we get to see what happens:

```
  def initialize(f = 0, c = 0)
    puts "f is #{f.inspect}"
    puts "c is #{c.inspect}"
  end
```

Your call:

```
Temperature.new(:f => 32)
f is {:f=>32}
c is 0
```

Clearly that's not what you want, and why you get an error later on. Here's how you'd have to call it:

```
Temperature.new(32)
f is 32
c is 0

Temperature.new(0, 32)
f is 0
c is 32
```

I'd by the way say that `nil` would be a better default than `0`, because `0` is a perfectly valid temperature. And it's bad having to provide some `f` value in order to provide a `c` value.

#### Hash Argument

Above we saw that Ruby created a hash for you which then became the argument the method got. So you could change the method signature to reflect that, i.e., take a hash, and then extract the values from it:

```
  def initialize(options)
    f = options[:f]
    c = options[:c]
    puts "f is #{f.inspect}"
    puts "c is #{c.inspect}"
  end
```

Now you can use it like you did:

```
Temperature.new(:f => 32)
f is 32
c is nil

Temperature.new(:c => 32)
f is nil
c is 32
```

Note that this way you do get `nil` as default. You can also use this nicer syntax:

```
Temperature.new(f: 32)
f is 32
c is nil

Temperature.new(c: 32)
f is nil
c is 32
```

#### Keyword Arguments

Almost five years ago already, [Ruby 2 came out and brought us keyword arguments](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/02/24/ruby-2-0-0-p0-is-released/). Now instead of only *creating* a hash for you, Ruby can also be told to *take it apart* for you. Like this:

```
  def initialize(f: nil, c: nil)
    puts "f is #{f.inspect}"
    puts "c is #{c.inspect}"
  end
```

You can still call it as before:

```
Temperature.new(f: 32)
f is 32
c is nil

Temperature.new(c: 32)
f is nil
c is 32
```

Doesn't `initialize(f: nil, c: nil)` look much more meaningful than `initialize(options)`? It even looks very much like the calls now. And you don't need extra code to extract the values from the hash. Also, if you mistype an argument name, you now get an error:

```
Temperature.new(x: 32)
ArgumentError: unknown keyword: x
```

The single hash parameter solution would just set `f` and `c` to `nil` and happily move on as if there were no problem.

You can btw still call it even with an explicit hash and the rocket notation, though I'm just showing that for additional understanding:

```
Temperature.new({:f => 32})
f is 32
c is nil
```