# How do I set a keyword arg to default to undefined in Ruby

Tags: ruby, optional-parameters

I have the following code

```
def thing(item: "yeah")
  puts item == nil
end  
def thing2(item: nil)
  thing(item: item)
end
thing2()
```

I would expect to see `false` because I would expect the `nil` passed to `thing` to be seen as an undefined `item` parameter, however, I see `true`. I am suspecting that this is because, like JS, ruby separates `nil` from `undefined`. So is there a way that I can default the value to `undefined` instead of `nil`?

**My current final version based on the accepted answer looks like this...**

```
def default_item 
  "yeah" 
end
def default_other 
  "other" 
end

def thing(item: default_item(), other: default_other())
  puts item + " " + other
end  
def thing1(other: default_other())
  thing(other: other)
end  
def thing2(item: default_item())
  thing(item: item)
end
thing1()
thing2()
thing1(other:"Is Other")
thing2(item:"Is Item")
# fail with argument exception
# thing1(item:"Not Item")
# thing2(other:"Not Other")
```

[Code Example](https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/XNTIYJCFLG)

(The method returning a value is more based on it needing to actually return an instance value)

I still don't like the `item: default_item()` all over the place so I am open to a better solution.

Comment: "I would expect the nil passed to thing and see false" – Huh? Why would you expect this to print "false" if `nil` gets passed as an argument to `thing`? You *literally* check whether you are passing `nil`, so of course it prints "true".

Comment: Because I would expect the keyword param in the method call to set it because it is null. So I am guessing this isn't happening because it only sets the value if it is undefined and null != undefined. So how can I declare it so that instead of nil it will be undefined

Comment: @JörgWMittag he wants `thing` to see that `item` is `nil`, and interpret this as `item` being unset, and thus defaulting `item` to `"yeah"`

Comment: @River thanks yeah so I kind of understand why it doesn't but now I need to know how I can make it work. I don't want to redeclare default values everywhere that calls the thing method.

Comment: @Jackie Don't you have to declare a default parameter using `nil` here anyways? Why is that better than using `"yeah"`? You can always do an `if` check: `if item then thing(item) else thing() end`

Comment: lets just be super clear that ruby is not javascript and that "undefined" is a run time error (`NameError`). If you consider this separation then I guess yes ruby separates these things.  If you want a default in the case of `nil` then this would be `item ||= "yeah"` in the thing method.

Comment: @engineersmnky fair enough I had yet to yet that bump (another definition for undefined in ruby) yet ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ruby, being `nil` and being absent are two very different things.

When `thing2` calls `thing` with `item=nil`, `thing` realizes `item` is present, but with `nil` as its value. Thus the check `item==nil` returns `true`.

I think your two best options are manually checking for `nil`, and just using the same default as your other method:

Option 1:

```
def thing(item: "yeah")
  puts item == nil
end  
def thing2(item: nil)
  if item!=nil
      thing(item: item)
  else
      thing()
  end
end
thing2()
```

Option 2:

```
$DEFAULT = "yeah"
def thing(item: $DEFAULT)
  puts item == nil
end  
def thing2(item: $DEFAULT)
  thing(item: item)
end
thing2()
```

Comment: Option 2 now looks like the most decent. Is there a way I can do that with a instance level instead of a global level var? I tried def initialize @default = "blah" end but that didn't work

Comment: @Jackie Yea, if you just initialize the instance variable in `initialize`, it should work. Glad it was helpful

Comment: Accepted answer until someone comes up with a better one :-) I would still like to not have `item: DEFAULT` all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

You call `thing2()`, so `item` in `thing2` gets its default value `nil`. Which it then gives to `thing`. So `item` in `thing` is `nil` as well. If you want it to be `"yeah"` instead, then you need to call `thing` truly *without* a value for `item`. Not with the `nil` value.

One way to do that would be to use a hash parameter instead of the keyword argument:

```
def thing(item: "yeah")
  puts item == nil
end  
def thing2(options = {})
  thing(options)
end
thing2()
thing2(item: nil)
```

That prints `false` for `thing2()` because `thing2` doesn't get an `item` value and thus doesn't give an `item` value to `thing`. So `thing` uses the default `"yeah"`.

And it prints `true` for `thing2(item: nil)` because `thing2` does get an `item` value and forwards it to `thing`, and it's `nil`.

Not sure whether that's a good idea, I guess it depends on your actual use case.

Edit: As @SergioTulentsev commented, you can also still use keyword arguments:

```
def thing(item: "yeah")
  puts item == nil
end  
def thing2(**kwargs)
  thing(**kwargs)
end
thing2()
thing2(item: nil)
```

That's probably better, consistently using keyword arguments everywhere.

Comment: Interesting way to handle that never thought of using a "fake" default value.

Comment: You can still use keyword arguments. `def thing2(**kwargs)`. But yeah, it's basically the same hash underneath.

Comment: @Jackie What do you mean? There's nothing fake here. I recently wrote an [answer about different parameter styles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47728074/1672429), maybe that helps clarify this.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Nice. Should I forward by calling `thing(kwargs)` or by calling `thing(**kwargs)`? Both seem to have the same effect and I guess it's just a matter of style?

Comment: @StefanPochmann: I'd use `thing(**kwargs)`. The other way might work now, but conceptually, kwargs and one positional hash arg are two very different things (and so they may reimplement kwargs in the future)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yeah, and using different styles for taking and passing arguments rather feels wrong. Thanks, added to the answer.

Comment: This looks to work well for this version, however, I have issues if I expand it to my actual use case. Imagine this example https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/AWCRRTJAHT. Using the explicit declarations everything works and the other is ignored on thing2 (giving me yeah other). But when I use the **args version I get yeah blah.

Comment: Code for it not working with var args here https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/YZPLXURHDX

Comment: @Jackie: what do you mean, "not working"? As far as I can understand your spec, it works just as you want.

Comment: This one, the last line says "Yeah blah" when it should be "yeah other" https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/YZPLXURHDX

Comment: @Jackie Why should it say "other"? That's only the default, used in case no value is provided, but you do provide one.

Comment: Because in https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/AWCRRTJAHT it does and that is what the code would replace. Also see above answer it explains what actually worked

Comment: @Jackie If that works then I don't understand why you would replace it...

Comment: @Jackie I think you'd best describe all usages and what you expect from each. As far as I can tell, my solutions work for what you have in your question, and the codepad versions you mentioned in these comments don't make it clear what you want. All of a sudden there's a second parameter and it's really not clear how the whole thing is supposed to behave.

Comment: @StefanPochmann see if my update to the question helps clarify a bit. I tried to add some test case examples

Comment: @Jackie Using my way there results in the exact same four outputs.