# How to render view in parent controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, view, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to pass down values from a parent controller, to the views of the child, or ideally, render the view directly from the parent controller.

Here is my parent controller:

```
class SuperBlogPostsController < ApplicationController


def index(country)
    if country == "AUSTRALIA"
      @posts = AustraliaBlogPost.all
    hash = { posts: @posts, featured_post: AustraliaBlogPost.find_by(featured_post: true) }
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html {render 'super_blog_post/index'}
        format.json {render json: hash}
    end
end
end

def show(country)
    if country == "AUSTRALIA"
        @post = AustraliaBlogPost.find(params[:id])
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html {render 'super_blog_post/show'}
        format.json {render json: @post}
    end
end
```

end

And here is my child:

```
class AustraliaBlogPostsController < SuperBlogPostsController

  def index
    super(country: 'AUSTRALIA')
  end

  def show
    super(country: 'AUSTRALIA')
  end
end
```

This is the error that I get, even when I append .json at the end of the url:

[image: Error Message]

Is it possible to do the rendering of the view in the parent, or at least pass down the return values of the variables generated by the parent to the  child? If I've been unclear at all, let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: It's better if you post the error message as text instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parent controller methods accept a normal parameter, not [named parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15062570/368167).

Instead of:

```
super(country: 'AUSTRALIA')
```

You need

```
super('AUSTRALIA')
```

But I must say, the entire logic of your controllers doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm not having a problem with passing the parameters to the parent, but I'm having a problem getting the parent to render the views. I have a ton of these "CountryNameBlogPostControllers" so I want to write as little code as possible. The way I am passing the parameters from the child to the parent is working as I want it to.

Comment: If it doesn't throw an error that doesn't necessarily mean it's working properly. Are you sure it is working? did you try to `puts country` in the parent controller to see if it actually has a value?

Comment: That worked! You were right about the named parameter. Thanks for the help!